# Capitalising Contractions

Tags: capitalization, apostrophe, contractions

I couldn't really find anything on this, but it has been bugging me for a while.

Say for example, you have the following dialogue:

> 'I'll let Mr. Hall know.'

If you want to emulate "dropping the H" (similar to dropping the "A" and "D" in "fish 'n' chips"), does the first letter after the apostrophe have to be capitalised:

> 'I'll let Mr. 'All know.' **vs.** 'I'll let Mr. 'all know.'

Comment: @sumelic Helpful, but not 100%. I was hoping for some more detailed or referenced answers.

Comment: @sumelic Thank you very much for that; I'll make sure to keep an eye on it.